# Refresh Facebook Token PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook

The facebook docs state that [Facebook's official SDKs manage the lifetime of tokens for you](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), but then they go to say that

> When using iOS, Android or our JavaScript SDK, the SDK will handle making sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire.

So... does that mean that the PHP SDK does not manage refreshing for us?

A [user on reddit believes](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/2ydlcy/renewing_long_lived_facebook_access_tokens_on/) that the PHP SDK does in fact manage it for us.

So if I have a long-lived token with an expiration of 60 days, do I need to renew it at day 59 or will the SDK do it for me if I'm making calls within that 60 days?

Comment: Here's a thread suggesting that we just use the JS SDK to do it transparently on the front end. Not a bad idea. https://disqus.com/home/discussion/sammyk/how_to_handle_access_tokens_with_facebook_sdk_v4_78/oldest/

Comment: Are you referring to _“You get a long-lived token one time, and then every time it's used it's automatically renewed for 60 days”_? That is just plain wrong. It would make little sense to implement a 60 day expiry, if the tokens kept refreshing themselves every time they are used. // There is _no way_ to get a new token without user interaction.

Comment: @CBroe Did you read my quote from the Facebook Docs? _When using iOS, Android or our JavaScript SDK, the SDK will handle making sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire._ So when you say _It would make little sense to implement a 60 day expiry, if the tokens kept refreshing themselves every time they are use_ it seems like that is in fact **exactly** what they are doing. I just need to know if the PHP SDK does the same.

Comment: With the client-side SDKs, those will be short-lived tokens – and they are automatically refreshed, _because_ there is user interaction. With the PHP SDK, you will have to send the user through the login flow again (which will redirect them right back to your app, if they granted it permission before already), to get a new token.